# Duplicate keys detected (no v-for)

Tags: vue.js

For some reason I keep getting this error

Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error.
 Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.

I tried binding the key with v-bind:key="'test'+form.nbEtapes" for example but it doesn't help... Any idea?

It is since I added this to my form:

```
<form class="form" @submit="submit" method="post" novalidate="true">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nbEtapes">Nombre d'étapes</label>
    <input id="nbEtapes" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="range[1;50]" type="number" key="nbEtapes" v-model="form.nbEtapes">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please update question the object `form`? What in the form or in the `form.nbEtapes`?

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend creating a [mcve]. With currently posted code it is impossible to reproduce the bug and, therefore, to test any possible solutions. And second of all, even though it's thrown using a `console.error` (which is kind of wrong), opening it will reveal it's a `warn @`. And, by all accounts, it's a warning of something which ***might*** result in an error.

Comment: what's the type of nbEtapes if it's an object that's what giving you a warning. Try using a primitive like key="nb-etapes-test1" to see if it works.

Comment: Why do you need a key attribute in the input?